# Game Terrain Sprite Rotation

Tags: java, json, graphics

I'm making an RPG game. I'm working on a map editor which I can use to design the game's world. Now as I'm creating the sprites, I see that I will have stuff like a beach, where grass meets sand. I make a 32x32 sprite, half of it consisting of my grass sprite and the other half consisting of my sand sprite, respectively.

Now let's say I want to use this same sprite, but it's mirror image. Sand comes first, then grass.

My map editor saves the map by using JSON, so I can't save the Image, I have to save an URL to retrieve the image when I play my game. So how can I be sure to save some sort of information that specifies how this image should be drawn, whether it be rotated 180 degrees or it's mirror image? How can I perform these changes to my image?

Comment: Have you considered posting on gamedev.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the JSON used to drive the map/editor should contain information about the orientation of the tile and anything else the map location may need. For example:

```
{
  "name": "Isle of Dread",
  "locations": [
    {
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0,
      "terrain": "sand",
      "tile": {
        "url": "/tiles/grassy-beach.png",
        "orientation": "north"
      }
    },
    {
      "x": 0,
      "y": 1,
      "terrain": "sand",
      "tile": {
        "url": "/tiles/grassy-beach.png",
        "orientation": "east"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The code for actually rotating and drawing your tile will be dependent upon the technology you are using. Many graphics frameworks have ways to rotate an image.